# How to open custom view in same window in sugarcrm..like quick compose email view in leads module of SugarCRM

Tags: javascript, email, sugarcrm, popupwindow

I have made a email functionality in a custom view using JavaScript. The problem is on clicking the send email button in list view it goes to this window and previous window is gone. I want my custom view for emailing to popup just like the default quick response email, that pops up when we click Email button in quick action menu in leads module in SugarCRM. Can anybody suggest how it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Popup in a new window with a defined size using javascript

```
function popup (url) {
    foo = window.open(url, "Popup", "width=400,height=300,resizable=yes");
    foo.focus();
    return false;
}
```

or take a look at [JQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)